# How to create database design to store product as a new product and popular product?

Tags: mysql

I have a one product table in MYSQL. Now i need to show product as new product and popular product. which is best practice to use these new fields. Should it add into same db table of products or need to create another new ? Do we need to create two separate table for this two new fields ? or can we use one table for this ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is Create a new table lets say Product_Status and have fields as Status_Id and Status_Description.And in main table add a column as PStatus. Now what you do is you assign a number for the status you want to add in Product_Status table(ex: Status_Id=10,Status Description:New Product) .You can link the two table with foreign keys. and enter the status_id in the main table's PStatus.

Comment: What you means to add in main table to add PStatus ? Do you means to add this field in main product table ? If yes, then i think its no meaning to create separate table. Because in this case i can create new field "newproduct" as in main product table ? I just want that is there possible without add any new field in main table of product ?

Comment: I didn't quite get you there, i think what you want is not to add any new field in Main product table but want to show the product as either new or popular. If this is what you want than what you can do is to create a link table between the Main table and the status table. Yes the status table is needed, also you need to create a new one. It gets tricky here. What you do now is that you add the product status and the associated the product id in the link table. And you can use `JOIN` to retrieve it